# SAS Concatenate Multiple Variables to Create Data-Driven Macro Statements

Tags: sql, macros, sas, append, concatenation

In order to keep my process data-driven, I'm trying to concatenate multiple variables, separated by comma, in order to ultimately put them in a `PROC SQL` list to call in multiple macro statements that would otherwise clutter my SAS pogram.

Take the following sample dataset:

```
DATA TEST;
  INPUT YEAR CONDITION $ QRTS $12. SAMPLE $;
  DATALINES;
  2008  MI  (1,2,3,4)   A
  2008  MI  (1,2,3,4)   B
  ;
RUN;
```

I'd like to concatenate these variables together, again separated by comma, and add `%APPEND` to the front to create a huge list of macro statements. The new string variable, and ultimately the macro statements, would look like:

`%APPEND(2008,MI,(1,2,3,4),A);`

`%APPEND(2008,MI,(1,2,3,4),B);`

I've used the following to compile strings of means and confidence intervals, and I would imagine it would also be similar (I just cannot figure out these quotes, commas, and bars with my data):

`ci=compress(put(mean,7.2))||"("||compress(lo)||","|| compress(hi)||")";`

Once this long string variable is created, I would select this variable into a long list through `PROC SQL` statement to be something like:

```
PROC SQL;
    SELECT DISTINCT *NEW LONG STRING VARIABLE*
    INTO: MACROLIST SEPARATED BY ' '
    FROM TEST;
QUIT;
```

Ultimately, running `&MACROLIST.` will call in hundreds of macro statements to append multiple datasets into a large master dataset. I appreciate the insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered my own question. This does what I need:

```
DATA TEST1; SET TEST;
    STRING=COMPRESS(%NRSTR("%APPEND""("||COMPRESS(YEAR)||","||COMPRESS(CONDITION)||","|| COMPRESS(QRTS)||","|| COMPRESS(SAMPLE)||")"),"""");
RUN;
```

`%APPEND` can then be replaced by any macro name created, so this could be very useful.

Comment: Look into the `catx()` function to simplify your code.  Your statement would become `string=catx(',','%append(',year,condition,qtrs,sample,')');`

Comment: I thought `catx()` could only allow for two variables -- I didn't know you could string together multiple with the function. I'll look into it -- thanks!